# sshfs mount and permission

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, sshfs

I'm gonna go crazy!
I've been trying to handle a sshfs mounted folder for several days, but always get a permission denied on file.

The context:
Local Server (L) and a Remote server (R).
Only user X is allowed to connect to the remote server R with SSH.

Same users, groups, uid and gid on both servers...
User X in Group X (uid 249, gid 249)
User B in group B (uid 30001, gid 30001)
User A in Group A (uid 30000, gid 30000), in group X (gid 249) and in group B (gid 30001)

On Server L before mounting under root user:

```
$ll /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  4 16:21 prod
```

For mounting, add the following line in /etc/fstab under root user:

`User_X@Server_R:/ /mnt/prod fuse.sshfs defaults,default_permissions,allow_other,_netdev,reconnect,noatime,auto 0 0`
Status after mounting:

```
$mount -a
$ll /mnt
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 12 10:26 prod
```

Now I can browse /mnt/prod under root user or User_A:

```
$ll /mnt/prod/path_to_my_remote_folder
drwxrwx--- 1 User_B Group_A 4096 Jan 13 08:43 my_remote_folder
$cd my_remote_folder
$ll
-rw-rw---- 1 User_B Group_B 397055 Jan 13 06:00 my_file.zip
```

Then trying to read (cat) or write (vi) my_file.zip under root or User_A:

```
$cat my_file.zip
cat: my_file.zip: Permission denied
$su User_A
$cat my_file.zip
cat: my_file.zip: Permission denied
```

On server R, I can open or write my_file.zip with root or User_A...

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?
Thanks!!

Comment: Is User_B part of Group_B? Can you do a `id User_B` and `groups User_B`?

Comment: id User_B --> uid=30001(User_B) gid=30001(Group_B) groups=30001(Group_B)

Comment: groups User_B --> User_B : Group_B

Comment: Modify /etc/fstab: Try by removing either of the `default_permissions` or `allow_other` and try again?

Comment: Already tried and same result...